# Чего только не было/чего только ни было

Tags: грамотная-речь, не-или-ни

*Танцы, бег в мешках, выступление кавээнщиков − чего только **не/ни** было на том вечере.*
Интернет говорит, что мне нужно "не". Если б было так: "Танцы, бег в мешках, выступление кавээнщиков... Чего только не было на том вечере!" − то было бы все ясно. Но как быть с моим повествовательным предложением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Танцы, бег в мешках, выступление кавээнщиков − чего только **не было** на том вечере.*

**Пояснение**

1. Вторая (присоединительная) часть предложения − это в любом случае **риторический вопрос**, даже если там стоит точка. А это значит, что здесь используется отрицательная частица НЕ, а не усилительная частица НИ.

**Примеры предложений**: Кто только не бывал у Горького! Как не любить родной Москвы! Ну как не порадеть родному человечку!

2. Сложные предложения **с частицей НИ** имеют **другую структуру**. Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным уступительным и союзами КТО НИ, КАК НИ, ГДЕ НИ и др.

**Примеры предложений** (с уступительным и обобщающе-усилительным значением): *Не мог он ямба от хорея, **как мы ни бились**, отличить.  **Куда ни обращаю взор,** кругом синеет мрачный бор и день права свои утратил.*

3. Сравнить: *Чего **ни вспомнишь**, все было на том вечере: танцы, бег в мешках, выступление кавээнщиков.* Здесь усилительно-обобщающее значение, союз **ЧЕГО НИ.**